# Forms of Alternating Skipping Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following sequence, where the two consecutive terms are positive and the next two are negative, and so on:

$$ a_n = 1 , 1, -1 , -1 , 1 , 1 , -1 , -1 , 1 ...$$

I've managed to think up some way of writing the sequence:

$$a_n = (-1)^\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor$$

$$ a_n = \sqrt2 \cdot\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (\sin x) ,  \text{at }x=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Are there other ways that this sequence be written as? I would imagine there is a way to write it implicitly but I can't think of it.

Edit: Also adding this ugly one I forgot to initially:

$$a_n=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } n \text{ is divisible by 4};\\1 & \text{ if } n-1 \text{ is divisible by 4};\\-1 & \text{ if } n-2 \text{ is divisible by 4};\\-1 & \text{ if } n-3 \text{ is divisible by 4}\end{cases}$$

Comment: As an aside, in a comment you made on a now deleted answer below, you say you were unfamiliar with notation such as $3\mid n$.  This is just a symbolic way of saying $3$ "divides" $n$, or equivalently that $n$ is divisible by $3$, $n$ is a multiple of $3$, etc...

Comment: $(-1)^\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor$ is certainly my favorite.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Try this
$$
(-1)^{\large \frac{n(n-1)}2},\qquad n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$

Comment: what about n=6?

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani -- The above answer starts the indices at $0$ rather than $1,$ so that $n=6,$ which gives $-1,$ really goes with the OP's $a_7=-1.$

Comment: OK, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if }  n=4k+1 or \text{  } n= 4k+2;\\-1 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that this sequence is periodic with period $4$. A similar procedure may be conducted with any periodic sequence. Index the sequence from $0$. Then the sequence is the solution of the recurrence relation
$$
a_n=a_{n-4};\quad (a_0=1,a_1=1,a_2=-1,a_3=-1)
$$
This recurrence relation has characteristic equation $r^4-1=0$ and thus roots $r=1,-1,i,-i$. (In general if the sequence has period $k$, then the roots of the characteristic equation will be the $k$ roots of unity). The solution then is
$$
a_n=c_0+c_1(-1)^n+c_2i^n+c_3(-i)^n\quad (n\geq0)
$$ 
where the $c_i$ are determined such that $a_0=1,a_1=1,a_2=-1,a_3=-1$. This corresponds to solving a system of equations.

The sequence may also be encoded as the coefficients of the generating function
$$
F(x)=\frac{1+x-x^2-x^3}{1-x^4}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

A trig version using that sin, cos of $(\pi/2)n$ are $\pm 1$ of period $4$ is
$$a_n=\sin \frac{\pi}{2}n - \cos \frac{\pi}{2}n.$$
[from the periodicity it only needs checking for $n=1,2,3,4.$]